# Quantidade de arquivos na requisição com Moq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testes, moq

O `SetupGet` para para o formulário (`Form`) da requisição funciona, porém o `Count` não funciona.
Como resolver para o `Count` retorne o valor desejado?

```
var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);            
httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Form).Returns(form);
httpContextMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Files.Count).Returns(2);
```